# How to add an HTML class to all image attachments on posts in Wordpress -- except homepage

Tags: wordpress

Sorry for the length, my problem is very simple, but specific.

I'm building a wordpress site that automatically imports image galleries from a Tumblr account, then styles and displays them. The backend is finished, and all that I need now is have all images in posts be displayed as thumbnail sized links. They are not behaving well with the importer (I've tried 6), so I have to edit the HTML display (rather than the images as they are uploaded).

I have decided to do this by applying `class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail"` on all images on the site (in HTML). I have tested this and they will open the proper gallery in a lightbox as necessary so long as they belong to those two classes.

I have a two part problem.

1. I do not know PHP past basic syntax, and while I can intuit most of what is happening I don't trust myself to edit Wordpress source code without understanding exactly what I am breaking.

From other answers I've learned that I should most likely edit the wp_insert_attachment() function in post.php under wp_includes/. I have found the function, but don't really know where to go from there, as it does not appear to be specific to image attachments. I don't want to throw any errors by assinging image classes to non-image attachments. How do I add those two classes (attachment-thumbnail and size-thumbnail) to all post images (and only images)?

2. There is a single exception to this rule. I want a large image on the homepage, and have it not be a link.

It seems like the way to handle this would be to allow page attachments to be handled normally, while attachments that are both images and attached to posts should trigger this:

if [attachment is an image AND is on a post, not a page]:

`<img src="https://whatever">`

becomes

`<img src="https://whatever" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail">`

tl; dnr: ^^ that's all I need to happen, in PHP, in the right file, in Wordpress ^^

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So likely you will want to do it via php but instead you could do it with javascript ie jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("body img").addClass("attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail");
    });    
</script>
```

Put that on any page or site header and it will add the class to all images. You can modify the search filter to suit.

You might need to re-call your lightbox initialization code too, or put this before it gets called initially.

Comment: Thank you. That's a lot simpler. Can I drop that into a PHP file that renders the header of my HTML?

Comment: It could be put in an javascript (.js) file that is called, or "inline" in the html itself, either in a template file with say the header html or a php that generates html. Anyway, anywhere. But like i said, best to put it before your light box script, is called. you might need to track that down.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, ive done this once before some years ago. Im not sure how much jQuery experience you have , but here's the reference for the function i used: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/ also the $(function() bit makes it only run the enclosed code once the page is finished loading

Comment: I've never used jQuery -- do I need to specify jQuery in the <script> tag in wordpress? or just type="text/javascript"?

Comment: wordpress might likely already have jquery , just try what i said, and check the console for any errors if its doesnt work

Comment: @Tbop Nowadays, the `<script>` take does not require anything else; in fact, since the only valid scripting language is JavaScript, adding `type="text/javascript"` has been deprecated and shouldn't be used any longer.